# which is better normal desktop window or MDI like excel and chronos

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-7, user-experience

i am creating a big application (ERP system) and i am confused to use 
- normal desktop screen and ribbon on top of the windows (DesktopToolbarWindow) like any window opening in the windows have a task bar icon ...
- or useing MDI like http://chronoswpf.codeplex.com/

can you help me with some prons and cons about MDI and

Comment: Can you give more details about the kind of application?

Comment: First, Excel is not MDI (and hasn't been for more than a decade), even though it tries to appear to be. Second, this is not a good question for SO, as it asks for discussion and opinion. Subjective questions are not a good fit here, as they can't be definitively answered. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions this type of question as not appropriate here. Voting to close as "not constructive".

Comment: @KenWhite - Actually, it's the other way around.  Excel *IS* MDI, but it pretends to be SDI.  You can tell because it still has the telltale child window management controls under the parent window controls.  If you click the child "restore winodw" you see it become a child window under the MDI.

Comment: @MystereMan - um, no. :) Unless it's changed in recent Office versions, Excel is not MDI (WinSpy and looking at window styles doesn't include any of the MDIS* styles, and there's no call to CreateMDIWindow()). Also see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which says you shouldn't use MDI unless there's not an alternative. Excel emulates some of the behavior, but isn't actually MDI.

Comment: @KenWhite - I'm aware that Microsoft does not recommend MDI anymore.  But Excel still uses the MDI interface, even if they're not using the classic MDI api's.  MDI is an interface style, and it's also a specific set of API's to achieve it.  You can still have MDI without using the MDI API's.

Comment: @MystereMan - I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree, then. :) On Windows, MDI typically has a specific meaning (that it uses the MDI APIs), and therefore an app that doesn't is not an MDI app. (It may emulate an MDI, but it isn't MDI.) No matter, though - just a difference of opinion regarding terminology. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely upon how you want users to interact with your system.  If you have multiple "documents", then MDI is usually indicated.  MDI stands for multiple document interface.  If you don't have multiple documents, then SDI is usually indicated (Single document interface).

But, without having much more detailed requirements, we couldn't guess.  You're the only one that knows what your app is going to do.

Comment: you are right the question is so generic, but is you have an experience with such thing you can help be mentioning MDI pros and cons.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed - There are no pros and cons.  It's a simple question.  If you have multiple documents, you use MDI.  If you have a single document, you use SDI.  That's all there is to it.